# Trying to pass input value as parameter

Tags: input, parameters, undefined

I just want to pass the value of the monthName(num) parameter but I am getting an error saying that num is undefined?

I have looked and looked and can't find any information on this, can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
    <input type="number" onkeydown="monthName(num)"> 
</body>
```

Comment: So where did you define it?

Comment: I don't know where to define it because it is an HTML statement, I must be missing something because I am thinking there must be something I need to add to pass the input to num?